# XSLT 1.0 Conditional Value

Tags: xslt-1.0

i have conditional like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="MsgIdBs">
                <xsl:variable name="dateB" select="substring($MsgIdB,1,8)"/>
                <xsl:variable name="biCodeB" select="substring($MsgIdB,9,8)"/>
                <xsl:variable name="trTpB" select="substring($MsgIdB,17,3)"/>
                <xsl:variable name="snB" select="substring($MsgIdB,20,8)"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="not(fn:matches($MsgIdB, '^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$') and string-length($MsgIdB) &lt;= 35)">
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="$MsgIdB"/>
                        </xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:variable name="flag" select="'false'"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="not(number(substring($dateB, 1, 4)) >= 1970 and number(substring($dateB, 5, 2)) &lt;= 12 and number(substring($dateB, 7, 2)) &lt;= 31)">
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="$MsgIdB"/>
                        </xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:variable name="flag" select="'false'"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="not(contains($trTpB,'010') or contains($trTpB,'011') or contains($trTpB,'019') or contains($trTpB,'110') or contains($trTpB,'510') or contains($trTpB,'610') or contains($trTpB,'710') or contains($trTpB,'720') or contains($trTpB,'000'))">
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="$MsgIdB"/>
                        </xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:variable name="flag" select="'false'"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="not(fn:matches($snB, '^\d+$'))">
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="$MsgIdB"/>
                        </xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:variable name="flag" select="'false'"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$MsgIdB"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
```

and i have a variable to check value from variable name flag. but i always get value from otherwise. never get value from variable flag on conditional. the code like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="output">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$flag = 'false'">
                        <ns2:TxSts>Not Deal</ns2:TxSts>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <ns2:TxSts>Deal</ns2:TxSts>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
```

how i can get the value from variable name flag on conditional and compare base with variable output.

Comment: The scope of a variable is its following siblings and their descendants. A variable defined in another variable does not exist outside of it.

Comment: Note also that your question is tagged `xslt-1.0` but the `matches()` function requires an XSLT 2.0 processor -as you have been already told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73906405/sending-value-with-different-tag-xslt#comment130497406_73906405).

Comment: Upon reread: *" i always get value from otherwise"* That's not possible. You must  be getting an error. Something is missing from your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Create a seperate variable for flag.  This will keep the flag varible in scope for use in following code.  

<xsl:variable name="flag">
  <xsl:variable name="dateB" select="substring($MsgIdB,1,8)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="biCodeB" select="substring($MsgIdB,9,8)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="trTpB" select="substring($MsgIdB,17,3)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="snB" select="substring($MsgIdB,20,8)"/>
  <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not(number(substring($dateB, 1, 4)) >= 1970 and number(substring($dateB, 5, 2)) &lt;= 12 and number(substring($dateB, 7, 2)) &lt;= 31)">
          <xsl:value-of select="'false'"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="not(contains($trTpB,'010') or contains($trTpB,'011') or contains($trTpB,'019') or contains($trTpB,'110') or contains($trTpB,'510') or contains($trTpB,'610') or contains($trTpB,'710') or contains($trTpB,'720') or contains($trTpB,'000'))">
          <xsl:value-of select="'false'"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="not(fn:matches($snB, '^\d+$'))">
          <xsl:value-of select="'false'"/>
      </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

Use the flag to create MsgIdBs.    
<xsl:variable name="MsgIdBs">
  <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($flag, 'false)">
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$MsgIdB"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="$MsgIdB"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

Use the flag again to create output.  
<xsl:variable name="output">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($flag, 'false)">
      <ns2:TxSts>Not Deal</ns2:TxSts>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <ns2:TxSts>Deal</ns2:TxSts>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```